# In R separate values in one column into two columns

Tags: r

I have a three-column dataset *df1* with this data:

```
ID  Age Games
1   36  10      
2   36  15      
3   36  20      
4   36  30      
1   37  40      
2   37  50      
3   37  35      
4   37  45
```

Here is the dput for the df1 dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), Age = c(36, 36, 
36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37), Games = c(10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 35, 
45)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want the data to be appear the way shown in the table below where the games for each ID's Age 36 and Age 37 values are now in separate columns:

```
ID  Age36 Age37
1    10     0      
2    15     0      
3    20     0      
4    30     0      
1     0    40      
2     0    50      
3     0    35      
4     0    45
```

My goal is to create from the second table a line chart with two line graphs, one for the Age36 games for each ID and the other for the Age 37 games, using pivot_longer to prepare the data for input into ggplot2 (unless you can recommend a better way of doing that).

Comment: I think the first dataset is better for `ggplot` instead of the second

Comment: Try `df1 %>% mutate(Age = factor(str_c('Age', Age))) %>% ggplot(aes(x = ID, y = Games, group = Age)) + geom_line()`

Comment: @akrun, how does the code in the parentheses work: ```mutate(Age = factor(str_c('Age', Age)?```

Comment: It is just to create a `factor` column with 'Age' as prefix.  The packages used are `library(dplyr); library(stringr)`

Comment: @akrun, why do you think the first dataset is better for ggplot?

Comment: Because it is already in the 'long' format.  In the second one, it is converted to a pseudo long format with columns as wide

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow this code

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(row, ID), names_from = Age, values_from = Games, values_fill = 0L) %>%
  select(-row)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
     ID  `36`  `37`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10     0
2     2    15     0
3     3    20     0
4     4    30     0
5     1     0    40
6     2     0    50
7     3     0    35
8     4     0    45
```

*Explanation:  Since your ID column is not unique we have to create a dummy ID column by using `row_number()` and in last we can unselect it.*